# Submit a form using onclick event, but only allow once

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onclick

I am both setting a form's action and submitting the form via the **onclick** event of a div:

```
<div class="action_button" onclick="document.forms['test'].action='url/to/action';document.forms['test'].submit()">
<span class="action_button_label">Save</span>
</div>
```

This works fine, but I'm wanting to use some code that conditionally checks for the 'Save' in the action_label_button, and only lets the submit() fire once. I'm trying to prevent multiple saves (which is yielding duplicate data in my app) from occurring.

```
// disable save buttons onclick (prevent multiple clicks of save buttons)

$('.action_button_label').one('click', function() {
    // if the button is a save button
    if($(this).html().indexOf('Save') != -1) {
        // submit the parent form
            $(this).html('<span class="action_button_label" style="color:gray;">Saving...</span>');
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
    }
});

$('form').bind('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('action_button').attr('onclick', '');
});
```

This code doesn't seem to work as I expected. I'm afraid I'm a  bit out of my depth here, any pointers would be great.

Comment: You probably just want to disable the button until the event is over.

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of this so that we can see and interact with your code.

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidangel/V5zKS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
$(this).find('action_button').attr('onclick', '');
```

with

```
$(this).find('.action_button').attr('onclick', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always handle multiple submits server side to ENSURE you don't get them. However you can hide the button-label to assist with this client side.

```
$('.action_button_label').one('click', function() {
    // if the button is a save button
    if($(this).html().indexOf('Save') != -1) {
        // submit the parent form
            $('.action_button_label').hide(); //ADD THIS
            $(this).html('<span class="action_button_label" style="color:gray;">Saving...</span>');
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
    }
});

$('form').bind('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('action_button').attr('onclick', '');
});
```

Comment: BenM, good advice on the server-side checks. I'll have to look into that solution as well.